# Kivy access .kv variables

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am working with Kivy for python and I was wondering if there is a way to access some variables that I declared in my .kv file like this:

```
#:set global_background_color_A (0.4,0.4,0.4, 1)
#:set global_background_color_B (0.2,0.2,0.2, 1)
#:set global_background_color_C (0.6,0.6,0.6, 1)
#:set global_seperator_color_Blue (0.26,.545,.65,1)
```

Now, it would be really nice if I could change the background color of some of my buttons dynamically in my python code. For this, I would have to access those variables.

What is the easiest way for doing so?

Thanks in advance,
Finn

Comment: Would have been much easier for me to get started answering if you'd posted a self-contained example (like I did), please consider that in future.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following code as an example app:

`controller.kv`

```
#:kivy 1.0
#:set global_background_color_A (0.4,0.4,0.4, 1)
#:set global_background_color_B (0.2,0.2,0.2, 1)
#:set global_background_color_C (0.6,0.6,0.6, 1)
#:set global_seperator_color_Blue (0.26,.545,.65,1)

<Controller>:
    label_wid: my_custom_label
    button_wid: my_custom_button

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 20

        Button:
            id: my_custom_button
            text: 'My controller info is: ' + root.info
            on_press: root.do_action()

        Label:
            id: my_custom_label
            text: 'My label before button press'
```

`__main__.py`

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.5')

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty

from kivy.lang.parser import global_idmap                   # <--


class Controller(FloatLayout):
    '''Create a controller that receives a custom widget from the kv lang file.

    Add an action to be called from the kv lang file.
    '''
    label_wid = ObjectProperty()
    info = StringProperty()

    def do_action(self):
        kv_var = global_idmap['global_background_color_A']  # <--
        self.label_wid.text = str(kv_var)                   # <--
        self.info = 'New info text'


class ControllerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Controller(info='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ControllerApp().run()
```

I've marked the important lines in `__main__.py` with arrows.

If you take a look at the kv language parser [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/1.10.0/kivy/lang/parser.py#L405), you can see what it's doing with the `set` command.  It does some error checking, and `eval()`s the value in the container `global_idmap`.

Now, I don't think this is recommendable.  As you can see [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/1.10.0/kivy/lang/parser.py#L25), kivy specifically doesn't expose `global_idmap`.  I would imagine it's an implementation detail which shouldn't be relied upon.

If you want to change the colour of your stuff in code, you can just do this:

```
def do_action(self):
    ...
    self.button_wid.background_color = (1, 0, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! :)